# Avoid duplicate actions for base class properties

Tags: c#, .net

I have multiple classes that inherit from a base class and I need to check values of this classes about I want to avoid from writing the same checks for the same properties of base class that where inherited

```
class baseClass
{
    public int Firstname;
    public string LastName;
    public string ID;
}

class TypeOneAditionalInformation: baseClass
{
   public string x1;
   public string x2;
}

class TypeTwoAditionalInformation: baseClass
{
   public int x3;
   public string x4;
}

public List<ErrorGet> TypeOneTest(TypeOneAditionalInformation _type)
{
  if(_type.Firstname!=null) ...
  if(_type.LastName!=null) ...
  if(_type.ID!=null) ...
  if(_type.x1!=null) ...
  if(_type.x2!=null) ...
}

public List<ErrorGet> TypeTwoTest(TypeTwoAditionalInformation _type)
{
  if(_type.Firstname!=null) ...
  if(_type.LastName!=null) ...
  if(_type.ID!=null) ...
  if(_type.x3!=null) ...
  if(_type.x4!=null) ...

}
```

I want to avoid from doing twice same checks on the same base type properties:

```
if(_type.Firstname!=null) ...
if(_type.LastName!=null) ...
if(_type.ID!=null) ...
```

what is the best practice for it ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a function to check for base type errors and call that function inside other two types.

Something like:

```
  public List<ErrorGet> BaseClassTest(baseClass _type)
  {
     if(_type.Firstname!=null) ...
     if(_type.LastName!=null) ...
     if(_type.ID!=null) ...
  }
```

Then call it from other two ...

```
  public List<ErrorGet> TypeTwoTest(TypeTwoAditionalInformation _type)
  {
    BaseClassTest(_type);
   ..
   ..
   if(_type.ID!=null) ...
   if(_type.x3!=null) ...
   if(_type.x4!=null) ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a validation framework to do such things and you'll save a lot of time.

For example, model validation being used in ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API can be used as a standalone validator.

Imagine there's a class `A` which has a `Text` property and you want to it as *not null*:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class A
{
    [Required]
    public string Text{get;set;}    
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<ValidationResult> errors = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if(Validator.TryValidateObject(new A(), null, errors))
        {
            // Do stuff if object validates
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, your base class can run the validator for `this`:

```
public class baseClass
{
    // Note I've switched your class fields to auto-properties
    [Required]
    public int Firstname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    protected virtual bool Validate()
    {
          List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();

          // Running it for "this" executes the validator for the most derived
          // class, so this includes ALL properties (from the base class to 
          // the most derived one!
          return Validator.TryValidateObject(this, null, results);
    }
}
```

This way, you can call `Validate` in derived classes and all properties will be automatically checked to be filled with some value, even properties from derived classes (you get an all-in-one solution).

There're many other validation attributes than you can apply to your properties [(check them in MSDN `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace documentation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In that case, use a parametrized constructor to initialize the members in base class using constructor initializer. Should be like below

```
class baseClass
{
    public string Firstname;
    public string LastName;
    public string ID;

  public baseClass(string fn, string ln, string id)
{
  this.Firstname = fn;
  this.LastName = ln;
  this.ID = id; 
}
}

class TypeOneAditionalInformation: baseClass
{
   public string x1;
   public string x2;

 public TypeOneAditionalInformation(string fn, string ln,
             string id, string x1, string x2) : base(fn, ln, id)
{
  this.x1 = x1;
  this.x2 = x2;
}
}
```

Comment: Rahul this solution not solving the problem of double check, I can update properties after instance created so I it will required from me to make the same check to each type with the same base class

Answer (score 0):

This is where polymorphism really becomes awesome!

What you should be doing is in your base class, declaring `TypeTest` as virtual. Then you should override it in each of your inherited classes, adding the additional functionality. Here is an example:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual void TypeTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FirstName != null ? "FirstName is NOT NULL!" : "FirstName IS NULL!");
        Console.WriteLine(LastName != null ? "LastName is NOT NULL!" : "LastName IS NULL!");
    }
}

class TypeOneAditionalInformation : BaseClass
{
    public string X1 { get; set; }
    public string X2 { get; set; }

    public override void TypeTest()
    {
        base.TypeTest();

        Console.WriteLine(X1 != null ? "X1 is NOT NULL!" : "X1 IS NULL!");
        Console.WriteLine(X2 != null ? "X2 is NOT NULL!" : "X2 IS NULL!");
    }
}

class TypeTwoAditionalInformation : BaseClass
{
    public string X3 { get; set; }
    public string X4 { get; set; }

    public override void TypeTest()
    {
        base.TypeTest();

        Console.WriteLine(X3 != null ? "X3 is NOT NULL!" : "X3 IS NULL!");
        Console.WriteLine(X4 != null ? "X4 is NOT NULL!" : "X4 IS NULL!");
    }
}
```

What this will allow you to do is just execute `TypeTest` without needing to worry about the types or properties. Here is an example:

```
var baseClass = new BaseClass();
var type1 = new TypeOneAditionalInformation();
var type2 = new TypeTwoAditionalInformation();

baseClass.FirstName = "Joe";
baseClass.LastName = "Miller";

type1.FirstName = "Rachel";
type1.LastName = "Miller";
type1.X1 = "72";

type2.FirstName = null;
type2.LastName = "Miller";
type2.X4 = "99";

var list = new List<BaseClass> {baseClass, type1, type2};
foreach (BaseClass obj in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    // Here is where polymorphism is magic!
    obj.TypeTest();
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

What's happening here is your program is dynamically called the appropriate `TypeTest` function at runtime. If `obj` is a `BaseClass` type, then your program will automagically know to call the `TypeTest` method inside `BaseClass`. Similarly, if `obj` is a `TypeOneAditionalInformation` class then your program will know to call the `TypeTest` inside that class.